# React Controlled Input Unable to Type [onChange]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Sorry if this sounds like a repeated question,I have checked the existing answer and none of them seemed to solve my problem.

I'm initially setting a value of a controlled input like so value =`{this.props.someValue}` (which comes from an API)

Later,I'm trying to let the user type the value on the form,

```
   class ProfilePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            lastname: "",
            errors : ""
        };
        this.handleOnchange = this.handleOnchange.bind(this);
    }
    handleInputChange = event => {
        const { target } = event;
        this.setState({
            [target.name]: target.value,
            errors: errors
        });
    };
    handleOnchange(event) {
        const { target } = event;
        this.setState({
            [target.name]: target.value
        });
    }

    render(){
    let firstName = [];
    let lastName = [];
    if (this.props.profile) {
        firstName = this.props.profile.first_name;
        lastName = this.props.profile.last_name;

    }
    return (
            <div class="container">

                        <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="First Name"
                            name="name"
                            value={firstName.value}
                            onBlur={this.handleInputChange}
                            onChange={this.handleOnchange.bind(this)}
                            className={
                                errors && errors.name
                                    ? "inputError"
                                    : "inputValid"
                            }
                        />
                </div>
    )
      }

}
```

My onChange event fires successfully however,it doesn't let me type anything in the input box.What Am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

You `value` logic is wrong. Whenever `this.state.name` changes you still keep sending `this.props.profile.first_name` as value.

`onChange` updates state and on re-render you need to check whether it has value or not.

My suggestion is to stick with `state` value and "ignore" `this.props.profile` on render method.

One possible solution is hand it over in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    ...
    name: this.props.profile ? this.props.profile.first_name.value : ''
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is re-rendered every time your `handleOnchange` function runs, due to the `this.setState({...})` call in it. That is correct so far, but you have to update the input `value` manually. At the moment, your input field re-takes the `value` `firstname.value` at every re-render, which is something static out of `this.props`, that's why the value will never change.

You only have to set the input `value` to the state variable you are updating in your `handleOnchange` function, for instance `this.state.name`. Furthermore, you have to initialise the state variable in the constructur with the value you want to display at load time (not with an empty string like now). In your example, that would mean:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name: props.profile.first_name.value,
        lastname: "",
        errors : ""
    };
    this.handleOnchange = this.handleOnchange.bind(this);
}
```

Additionally you are doing the `this` binding of your `handleOnchange` function twice, once in the constructor and once in the input field assignment. It would be sufficient to do it only in the constructor, since it is the preferred way of doing that. With that in mind, you can just assign the function in your input field like: `onChange={this.handleOnchange}`